# Как скопировать LinkName элемента и вставить в переменую?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

У меня есть бот, который заходит в ВК. Мне надо, чтобы, когда я захожу, отображалось в `Textbox` моё имя, но я не знаю, как имя из него вытащить и вставить в переменную.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из HTML как-то так видимо:

```
var div = driver.FindElement(By.Id("page_info_wrap"));
var name = div.FindElement(By.Class("page_name")).Text;
```

или так:

```
var nm = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#page_info_wrap .page_top > .page_name")).Text;
```